# Laravel Collection Sorting Desc/Asc Based On Condition

Tags: laravel-8

I have laravel elqueont collection and i want to sort it based on condition on status value, if status == 3 the ordering will be id desc else the ordering will be id asc, help please.

trying to sort laravel collection based on condition on anthor column value

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all about collection sorting on [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sort). So lets say you have 2 conditions your code will look like this

```
$collection = Model::all();
if($condition == 1) {
   $collection->sortBy('created_at');
} else {
   $collection->sortByDesc('created_at);
}
```

This is just a general idea, you can share your code  for further help.